# Serving manually set time

Tags: arch-linux, time, ntp

I have set my NTP config to this:

```
# local server
server 127.0.0.1
fudge 127.0.0.1 stratum 10

# Only allow read-only access from localhost
restrict -4 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Location of drift file
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

Leaving public `server` definitions out, assuming that this would server my machines time.

Now, I set my date with `date --set="+5 minutes"`, restart NTPd `systemctl restart ntpd`, and when I test my time server from Windows machine, I get:

> An error occured while Windows was synchronizing with 192.168.1.160.
>   The peer is unreachable.

Whenever I add other `server` definitions to the configuration, it works.

How would I set up an NTP server that'd serve manually set time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that [Local Clock (LCL) explicitly needs `127.127.1.1`](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-refclk.htm#Q-LOCAL-CLOCK) address instead of the default loopback, what I had assumed.

Quite tricky - that's what happens when you don't copy-paste configurations.